# Call to undefined method Goutte\Client::setClient()

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, guzzle, goutte

I am stuck with this error...
but the client is defined.

my code like this

```
use Goutte\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class WebScrapingController extends Controller
{
    public function doWebScraping() 
    {
        $goutteClient = new Client();
        $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array(
            'timeout' => 60,
            'verify' => false
        ));
        $goutteClient->setClient($guzzleClient);
        $crawler = $goutteClient->request('GET', 'https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Laravel');
        $crawler->filter('.result__title .result__a')->each(function ($node) {
            dump($node->text());
        });
    }
}
```

I think error from this line

```
$goutteClient->setClient($guzzleClient);
```

---

> goutte: "^4.0"
>  guzzle: "7.0"
>  Laravel Framework: "6.20.4"

---

Comment: the setClient method is deprecated from version 4.0, add instance directly into the constructor of Goutte

Comment: oh I got it. problem was it , thank you @bhucho . make an answer with detailed solution it could be  help others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is regarding creating instance of [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) client, a simple PHP Web Scraper

---

#### For Version >= 4.0.0

Pass HttpClient(either guzzle httpclient , symfony httpclient) instance directly inside the instance of Goutte Client.

```
use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;// or use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

$client = new Client(HttpClient::create(['timeout' => 60]));
// or 
// $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(['timeout' => 60, 'verify' => false]); // pass this to Goutte Client
```

---

#### For Version <= 4.0.0 (i.e from 0.1.0 to 3.3.1)

```
use Goutte\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

$goutteClient = new Client();
$guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(['timeout' => 60]);
$goutteClient->setClient($guzzleClient);
```

Comment: is there a way to pass any debug parameter in goutteClient?