# Behat Testing - GoutteFactory.php line 117

Tags: php, laravel, testing, behat

I try to run behat tests in a Laravel project.

When I run `bin/php vendor/bin/behat`:
I have this error:

```
In GoutteFactory.php line 117:
                                                    
  Method Goutte\Client::setClient() does not exist
```

My composer.json:

```json
"require": {
   "php": "^8.0.2",
        [...]
    
        "behat/mink":               "^1.9",
        "dmore/behat-chrome-extension": "^1.4",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^2.0",
        "dmore/chrome-mink-driver": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "behat/behat": "^3.10",
        "friends-of-behat/mink-extension": "^2.6",
     
        [...]
    }
}
```

My behat.yml:

```yaml
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      goutte: ~
```

Myfeature is a very simplest tests. It only uses rules provided by Mink, like "Given I am on "/".

My FeatureContext.php

```php
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements Context
{


}
```

Comment: Could [this info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66086046/7644018) possibly help?